# How can we achieve Round-Robin implementation in Redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am working on a scenario where i have multiple subscribers in Redis pub/sub implementation, but instead of broadcasting the message to all the subscribers i want to deliver a particular message to a single subscriber so that each subscriber will have unique message with them. In this scenario Round-Robin approach seems more reliable. How can we achieve this in Redis?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of PubSub, use a List to store messages by calling [`RPUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/rpush). Clients can use  [`BLPOP`](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) to atomically and exclusively consume the messages.

Note that this queue pattern doesn't necessarily mean true round-robin-ness, but it should converge to a similar result in most cases.